# JQuery Mobile datepicker loses theme when any options are set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm using JQuery Mobile with it's mobile themed datepicker plugin. Here is the relevant code, as per JQuery Mobile Datepicker demo, that works just as expected:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.datepicker.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //reset type=date inputs to text
    $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
    }); 
</script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script id="mobile-datepicker" src="jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="servicedate" name="servicedate" data-role="date" type="text" />
</body>
```

Above produces properly styled mobile datepicker tied to "servicedate" input like [this](http://i58.tinypic.com/mbk37q.jpg).

Now, any attempt to interact with datepicker, like dynamically changing any of the options, causes it to lose its mobile style. To the bottom of body, I add a:

```
<script>
  $("#servicedate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "DD, MM dd yy", }); 
</script>
```

... and it now, while option does work, produces rather unpleasant looking, un-themed datepicker like [this](http://i62.tinypic.com/vnhy10.jpg).

Any help/guidance with what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your inspector, try looking at the styling both before and after you custom formatting is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to jqueryUI.css to your header

Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I would prefer to not have to do this but its the only way I got it to work.

(edited)

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">